# Ошибка при работе с AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-dialog

Приложение вылетает, когда я пытаюсь открыть AlertDialog второй раз. Т.е. при первом открытия AlertDialog все хорошо, а при последующем открытии ошибка, в чем понять не могу, подскажите.
P.S.: Класс в котором происходит создание диалога - наследник от класса Fragment.

код в котором происходит создание диалога:

```
case R.id.remove_btn:
            //Удаляем элемент
            aDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            aDialog.setView(customDialog);

            final AlertDialog dialog = aDialog.create();
            dialog.show();

            dialogYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    deleteItem(position);
                    dialog.hide();
                }
            });

            dialogNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.hide();
                }
            });

            break;
```

сообщение ошибки:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.nikva.easyreading, PID: 11210
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4168)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4018)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3990)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.setupCustomContent(AlertController.java:647)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:463)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:226)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:257)
                  at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:373)
                  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:274)
                  at com.example.nikva.easyreading.RecentBooksFragment.onItemClick(RecentBooksFragment.java:112)
                  at com.example.nikva.easyreading.BookViewHolder.onClick(RecentBooksFragment.java:373)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5076)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20279)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:120
```

Comment: Может быть вы customDialog из строки aDialog.setView(customDialog);
 уже куда-то добавляли. Если да, то Вам советуют в этом случае сначала дать команду removeView(customDialog). В общем, было бы неплохо увидеть больше кода.

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь где-то сделать `View#addView(View view)` передавая `view` которая уже куда-то добавляли ранее. Т.к. вы не показали те строки где вы это делаете, то конкретнее сказать нельзя

Comment: Ну нет, я нигде не использую addView()

Comment: Могу даже весь код скинуть, там такого нет

Comment: @Ник, тогда попробуйте сделать переменную `aDialog` локальной

Answer (score 0):

Вот в этой строке

```
aDialog.setView(customDialog);
```

вы добавляете какой-то свой `View` сначала в первый диалог, а потом пытаетесь и во второй. К сожалению, содержимое нельзя использовать повторно, не удалив из предыдущего диалога.
По законам `Android UI`, если обьект `View` уже добавлен в контейнер, он не может быть добавлен в другой. В вашем случае диалог и есть контейнер.